# Is it possible to toggle text to strikethrough text in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I want to keep track of a todo list in Visual Studio Code.

Is it possible to display/toggle strikethrough text:

- task not yet done
- ̶t̶a̶s̶k̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶e̶

(used https://www.piliapp.com/cool-text/strikethrough-text/ for the above).

Looking for a solution natively or with an extension. The strike-through text needs to be displayed in the text file (like the functioning of org mode in emacs) and not in some output window (like the rendering of a HTML/Latex/MD document).

Any experts in Visual Studio Code that know if this can be done and how to do it ?

Comment: Why not use existing extensions like [Todo+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus). They use _.todo_ file extension though, seems more appropriate for a todo list, no?

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is an interesting suggestion. I m new to Visual Studio Code and currently use https://www.moo.do/ as todo list. As i m spending more and more time in the text editor, I would prefer to have a simple TODO system based on plain txt living in my text editor. I m drawn towards Emacs and org mode or VS Code with a suited extension like the one you suggested. It could work, even if crossing-though a task feels more gratiying to me. My question is also technical. Is it 'uberhaupt' possible to toggle between strike-out and normal text in VS code. How ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make <strike>strikethrough</strike> in vscode with the help of [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) extension:

```json
"todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "(~~.+?~~)|(✔.+?\n)|(\\[x\\].+\n)",
"todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
    "color": "none",
    "backgroundColor": "none",
    "textDecoration": "line-through"
},
```

Use patterns that you usually use for **done** todos. The above works for such:

```
[x] done
✔ done
~~done~~
```

After that you can either use plain typing or find some toggling extension or write one yourself.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the built in function of adding "~~" before and after the text
so its like:

```
~~strikethrough~~
```

which strikes the words in between.

This can be done without extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Try the extension "Strike for VSCode", looks very lightweight extension.

Highlight the text you want to strikethrough and hit CTRL K + backspace.
CTRL K + backspace again to toggle.

Comment: Dunno why, but Strike actually adds `-` between the characters, like `T-O-D-O`.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey You have to enable "strike.whitespace" in Settings>Extensions>Strike> after that it will not have - between white spaces

Answer (score 0):

For vscode with markdown all in one the default should be <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

To find your specific vscode settings <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the command pallet, then search for "Preferences: open keyboard shortcuts" then search for strike through or any other keyboard shortcut.